# Cannot click a radio button using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I have tried numerous xpath functions but I always get an error like the element is not clickable, someone suggested a for loop should be used, can someone suggest something?

```
<dd class="inline">
  <!-- ngRepeat: gender in genderList track by $index --><label class="option ng-scope" data-ng-repeat="gender in genderList track by $index">
     <input name="gender" value="0" data-ng-click="genderChange($index)" type="radio">
     <span class="round"></span>
     <p class="ng-binding">All</p>
  </label><!-- end ngRepeat: gender in genderList track by $index --><label class="option ng-scope" data-ng-repeat="gender in genderList track by $index">
     <input name="gender" value="1" data-ng-click="genderChange($index)" type="radio">
     <span class="round"></span>
     <p class="ng-binding">Male</p>
  </label><!-- end ngRepeat: gender in genderList track by $index --><label class="option ng-scope" data-ng-repeat="gender in genderList track by $index">
     <input name="gender" value="2" data-ng-click="genderChange($index)" type="radio">
     <span class="round"></span>
     <p class="ng-binding">Female</p>
  </label><!-- end ngRepeat: gender in genderList track by $index -->
</dd>
```

Comment: Please add your code and xpath which you were using to find that element

Comment: It says its too long?

Comment: Is there any exception ? Did you tried   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by));  ?

Comment: i believe this is angularJS app..why not use protractor for the same and i m quite sure all issues will get resolved of locating as well as clicking

Answer (score 2):

You can try using this:

```
IWebElement radioButton = driver.findElement(By.CssSelector(".yourRadioButton"));
radioButton.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

OR

```
radioButton.SendKeys(Keys.Space);
```

sometimes radio buttons and other controls dont respond to this:

```
radioButton.Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `javascriptexecutor` to simulate radio button click

```
jquery = $x("//dd[@class='inline']/label[0]/input")[0].click()
```

or you can use javascript as well

===============================
Selenium Click will work...if you get element is not clickable exception then **probably your xpath might be wrong.**.
make sure you select the input tag in your xpath like i mentioned above..
because if you choose any other tag other than input like label or dd you will get element is not clickable exception

can you post your xpath??

Comment: How do I modify this to click the male radio button i.e. value 1?

Comment: //input[@type='radio' and @value='1']

Comment: //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class = 'round']")).isSelected();
        //driver.findElement(By.name("gender")).isSelected();
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='gender'] [@value='1']")).isSelected();
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='radio' and @value='1']")).isSelected();
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/label/input[@name='gender' and @value='1']")).click();
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/label/input[@value='1']")).click();

Comment: i recreated the page and tried the following $x("//dd[@class='inline']/label/input[@value='1']")[0].click()....which worked for me...I think you should use wait till the page loads before you perform click action

Comment: Sorry to be detailed, is that the exact syntax you used?

Comment: yes i used $x("//dd[@class='inline']/label/input[@value='1']")[0].click() ...in console...you can use that using javascriptexecutor..

Comment: I am using selenium in eclipse, and the $x says its undefined, how do I correct this?

Comment: can you try ===document.evaluate("//dd[@class='inline']/label/input[@value='1']", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click(); in your javascriptexecutor.. this is javascript...\

Comment: === is an invalid expression

Comment: use only this         document.evaluate("//dd[@class='inline']/label/input[@value='1']", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click();        without "==="

Comment: Yes I have used wait

Comment: Can you load your page in chrome browser and execute that javascript in console...

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a wait issue. Sometimes WebDriver is too fast in executing commands and its possible that element is not yet completely loaded in the DOM to click.

To isolate the issue try using a Thread.Sleep before the Click operation. If wait is the issue then try using WebDriverWait

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
JavaScriptExecutor js = driver;
js.executeScript("document.findElementById('**idOfTheRadioButton**').click");
```